# add Header in CXF response

Tags: java, cxf

I would like to add a customer header in CXF response.

In fact, at server, i use an OutInterceptor to see a header.

```
public RLECompressionOutInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
}
@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage paramT) throws Fault {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Header> head = new ArrayList<Header>();

    head.addAll(paramT.getHeaders());
    for (Iterator<Header> i = head.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Header h = i.next();
        Element n = (Element) h.getObject();
        if (n.getLocalName().equals("transactionID")) {
            String transactionID = n.getTextContent();
            //transactionID is information of a "transactionID" header 
        }
    }
}
```

However, at Client, in InInterceptor, the header in the response is NULL.

```
public CompressingInInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage arg0) throws Fault {
    List<Header> head = new ArrayList<Header>();
    head.addAll(arg0.getHeaders());
    for (Iterator<Header> i = head.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Header h = i.next();
        Element n = (Element) h.getObject();
        if (n.getLocalName().equals("transactionID")) {
            transactionID = n.getTextContent();
            System.out.println("ID: "+transactionID);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know why the header is null in this case ? How to correct it, please ?